# Converting Sinatra Routes to .NET Routes

Tags: .net, regex, routes, sinatra

I am no Regex-Ninja, and was wondering if it would be possible to refactor my code for converting Sinata style routes `/:foo/:bar` into .NET style routes `/{foo}/{bar}`. The following code is my current implementation for this, and hopefully there is a cleaner (maybe regex?) solution.

```
    private static string Convert(string input)
    {
        string output = "/";
        var segments = input.Split(new[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        foreach (var segment in segments)
            if (segment.StartsWith(":"))
                output += "{" + segment.TrimStart(':') + "}/";
            else
                output += segment + "/";

        if (output.Length > 1)
            output = output.TrimEnd('/');

        return output;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you mean:

```
var replace = Regex.Replace("/bar/:foo/:lar", "/:([^/]*)", "/{$1}");
```